# How to deal with errors during series of SQL inserts?

Tags: sql, database, insert, logic, pseudocode

Let's say we have a user that signs up for our application & our signup sheet contains multiple fields. We want to store that information in different SQL tables. Our logic might look something like...

```
Insert a row in Table 1
Insert a row in Table 2
...
Insert a row in Table N
```

What is the accepted solution if an insertion error arises at some point during this process? How does one clean up the previous rows?

My initial assumption would be the use of foreign keys w/ "delete on cascade" assigned + a single deletion of the parent table's row on error. Is this ideal?

Comment: depending on how you insert these, they could be one transcation, and os all would fail, as you know the structure of your tables, you wouldn't have any error, as long you have all constraints deactivated, nothing should go wrong

Comment: @nbk I had no idea SQL Transactions were a thing, thanks for the information. Perfect for my use case!